# Calling Img From Base URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

So normally I would `<?php echo base_url();?>`but im not sure how to do it in this code.

```
<?php
    $path = 'home';
    $img = '<img src="../img/servare.png" alt="">';
    echo anchor($path, $img);
```

I have tried...

```
<?php
    $path = 'home';
    $img = '<img src="' <?php echo base_url();?>'../img/servare.png" alt="">';
    echo anchor($path, $img);
```

But the img is not showing, any ideas ?

Comment: where is your img folder?

Comment: In my root directory

Comment: make sure add `base_url()` and remove `../` you'll get `http://yourdomain.com/img/servare.png`. to check if your image source placed correctly, use the inspect element, find img tag, see the `src` copy and paste to another tab.

Comment: so like this `$img = '<img src="'<?php echo base_url();?>'.img/servare.png" alt="">'; `

Comment: You have too much php tags opened. Try `$img = '<img src="' . base_url('img/servare.png') . '" alt=""';`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. thanks ill try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is one of the three following options:

1. If you're trying to create a text with a link to the image:

   ```
   $this->load->helper('url'); // Load URL Helper for base_url() 
   $this->load->helper('html'); // Load HTML Helper for img() 
   $path= base_url('img/servare.png'); // generates text: siteroot/img/servare.png 
   $text = 'Visit Image';

   echo anchor($path, $text);
   ```

OUTPUT HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png">Visit Image</a>
```

2. If you're trying to display the image in the current page,

   ```
   $path= base_url('img/servare.png'); // generates text: siteroot/img/servare.png 

   echo img($path);
   ```

OUTPUT HTML:

```
<img src="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png" alt="">
```

3. If you're trying to display the image in the current page and open the full image when clicked as a link,

   ```
   $this->load->helper('url'); // Load URL Helper for base_url() 
   $this->load->helper('html'); // Load HTML Helper for img()

   $path= base_url('img/servare.png'); // generates text: siteroot/img/servare.png 
   echo anchor($path, img($path));
   ```

OUTPUT HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png">
   <img src="http://localhost/nedwara.com/img/servare.png" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I have added a update, that I implemented in the answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be:

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $path = 'home';
    $img = '<img src="<?php echo base_url('img/servare.png');?>" alt="">';
    echo anchor($path, $img);
```

Because as seen in http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

base_url:

> Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file.

Eg. If your site is http://example.com then:

base_url() returns "http://example.com"

and base_url('img/servare.png') will return "http://example.com/img/servare.png"